# Xi function representation

Tags: nt.number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

Would it be correct to write down the following, or is it completely wrong?

$$ \Xi(z) = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\pi x^2}  \theta''(x) \sin(zx) \, dx, $$

with

$$ \theta(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\pi n^2 x^2}. $$

The first is Riemann's Xi function. And the next also makes me suspicious:

$$ \Xi\left(\frac{1}{2} - it\right) = \frac{1}{2} \theta''(t) - \frac{1}{4t} \theta'(t) .$$

Sorry for such a basic question.

Comment: $\theta(x)$ is a divergent series, according to your definition. Did you mean regularization?

Comment: The Riemann Xi function $$\xi(s)=\pi^{-\frac{s}{2}}\, (s-1)\, \Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}+1\right)\, \zeta(s)\tag{1}$$ corresponds to the Mellin transform $$\xi(s)=s \mathcal{M}_x[f(x)](-s)=s \int\limits_0^\infty f(x)\, x^{-s-1}\, dx\,,\quad\Re(s)>1\tag{2}$$ where $$f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{2 \pi n^2}{x^2}-1\right) e^{-\frac{\pi n^2}{x^2}}\tag{3}.$$

Comment: So

$$\Xi(t)=\xi(\frac{1}{2}+i t)\tag{4}$$

corresponds to the Mellin transform

$$\Xi(t)=\left(\frac{1}{2}+i t\right) \mathcal{M}_x[f(x)]\left(-\left(\frac{1}{2}+i t\right)\right)$$ $$=\left(\frac{1}{2}+i t\right) \int\limits_0^\infty f(x)\, x^{-\left(\frac{1}{2}+i t\right)-1}\, dx\,,\quad\Im(t)<-\frac{1}{2}\tag{5}.$$

Comment: Annix sorry for the delayed response. The theta function $\theta(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\pi n^2 x^2}$ is analytic when the real part of $x$ is positive. It is also analytic in the upper half-plane where $\text{Im}(x) > 0$. The function also converges when the absolute value of its imaginary part is sufficiently larger than the absolute value of its real part. We should assume that $\theta(x)$ lies inside these strips.

Comment: Steven: by using classical ideas developed by Jensen, Hardy, and Polya, you can show that the Cahen-Mellin representation is made out of constant elements present in the entire functions 

$$\theta(e^t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\pi n^2 e^{2t}}$$ 

$$4w(t) = {e^t \theta(e^t)}$$ 

$$g(t) = w''(t) - w(t)$$.

Comment: All the zeros in the entire function $g(t)$ are contained within $-\pi/8<\text{Im}(t)<\pi/8$. The $\Xi(t)$ function zero's are contained within $-1/2<\text{Im}(t)<1/2$. The subtle oscillations occurring inside these imaginary intervals, particularly the oscillations in the angle (complex argument) in infinitesimally short intervals inside these intervals, suggested to me the representations 

$$\Xi(z) = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\pi x^2} \theta''(x) \sin(zx) \ dx$$ 

$$\Xi\left(\frac{1}{2} - it\right) = \frac{1}{2} \theta''(t) - \frac{1}{4t} \theta'(t)$$.

Comment: But these representations might be completely wrong

Comment: what exactly is $\Xi\left(\frac{1}{2} - it\right)$? Usually $\Xi(t)=\xi(\frac{1}{2}+i t)$ which would make $\Xi\left(\frac{1}{2} - it\right)=\xi(\frac{1}{2}+i (1/2-it))$ which sounds weird